# react-latex arrays

Tags: reactjs, latex, jsx

So after running into a ton of issues that left me reinstalling yarm, node, npm, and nvm, I can finally start testing [`react-latex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-latex). It seems to be working for simple expressions, but because of jsx using curly braces, I have been unable to use special LaTeX features such as arrays, I tried escaping the curly braces like this:

```
<Latex displaymode={true}>
  \left\begin\{arrray\}\{cc|c\}
     1 & 1 & 1 \\
     2 & 2 & 2 \\
     3 & 3 & 3 \\
  \end\{array\}\right
<Latex>
```

But literally every single escape throws an unicode error, so I tried escaping the escapes and got more unicode errors... I'm really just hoping that someone has already tried all the things I am about to try and could save me the headache. Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, using `{'{'}` would work, but that turns a string child into a list of string children, which `react-latex` can't handle. (it seems to be a rather basic package)

Looks like the best way to do it is therefore putting everything in a template string and escaping all backslashes and backquotes:

```
<Latex displayMode={true}>{`$$
  \\left(
  \\begin{array}{cc|c}
      1 & 1 & 1 \\\\
      2 & 2 & 2 \\\\
      3 & 3 & 3 \\\\
  \\end{array}
  \\right)
$$`}</Latex>
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-react-ug93qq?file=index.js).

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! I may or may not have eventually used template literals but this definitely saved me a lot of time and headache!

Comment: It might be worth noting that I had to add `.vertical-separator svg {display:none;}` to my css file to avoid a `400em` tall black box that showed up in the body with the augmentation separator, but that was not an issue in your StackBlitz example.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven Did you want me to add that to the answer?

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't hurt... I'm not sure if it is an issue on all platforms, but I don't think adding it will cause any functionality issues.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven It will probably hide all vertical separators, so you might not always want to do this. But if that's the reason the answer is not accepted, I can add it.

Comment: Sorry I actually just forgot to do it when I upvoted. It did not cause the separator not to diaplay when I did this, though (at least on a local test).